# Count function specific words

Tags: excel

i need help with my project
this pic for example

i need function to count only how many "IT" words front or equal "apple"
[this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr8Cr.png)

Comment: COUNTIFS..........

Comment: can you explain pls?

Comment: Please see the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842).

Comment: thank you man you saved my life:)